# get the webArchive that by webview saveWebArchive

Tags: android, webarchive

Android's WebView has this saveWebArchive method since API level 11:

It can save entire websites as webarchives, which is great! But how do I get the downloaded contents back into a webview? I tried

webview.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(mywebarchivefile));
But that only displays xml on the screen.

I try use WebArchiveReader who tell me can display the webArchive, but it just parse xml and i get the same result.

How can i do now?

Answer (score 2):

You can load the saved archive into your webView by first [reading the archive into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) and then calling:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, archiveString, "application/x-webarchive-xml", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Why pass **null** in first parm?

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

loadUrl with file:// scheme

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file://"+getContext().getFilesDir().getPath()+"/example.mhtml"); 
//file:///data/user/0/{your app package name}/files/example.mhtml
```

"Handle the content by yourself" version:

1. read every line of your mhtml file to a string (remember to add \r\n after each readLine())
2. `mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(/*source url, or even https://example.com/, don't put null or empty string*/, dataString, "multipart/related", "utf-8","");`