# SaveWebArchive method - trying to open archive

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to open a web archive in my **webView**. I can't find a path of this archive.

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 webView.loadUrl(url);
 webView.saveWebArchive("webArchive");
```

Now, where is this archive? What is path of this?
I think that I should use a `webView.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(my archive));`

, but what should I use in my archive field?
Thanks.

Comment: It's on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504404/get-the-webarchive-that-by-webview-savewebarchive

Comment: I think that it isn't working :/

Answer (score 4):

You use WebView.saveWebArchive in a wrong way. You should use it like this:

```
webView.saveWebArchive(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() 
        + File.separator + YOURARCHIVE_NAME+".xml");
```

Comment: Ok, i changed it. So when I use  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"webArchive","CHAPS/x-webArchive-xml","UTF-8",null);
on the screen of emulator I can see white bar with title "webArchive"

Comment: Is this volatile storage, or persistent?

Comment: Does `saveWebArchive()` have to be called asynchronously on a non-ui thread?